# Iterating through JSON table in Javascript

Tags: javascript, json

I'm trying to 'import' an external JSON table into my Javascript so I can iterate through it. Current results are that I just get `[Object object]` thing and no matter what I can't reach to the desired value.

My setup:

```
index.html
/js-
   core.js
   languages.js // <- same as below, but in js
languages.json
```

index.html:

```
<script src="js/languages.js"></script>
<script language="javascript" src="js/core.js"></script>
```

languages.js:

```
var data = {
"languages" : [{

  "english" :  {
    "dontRefresh" : "Do not refresh the page!",
    "..." : "...",
  }, 
  "russian" : {
  ...
  },
}] 
}
```

I tried the following and my local server crashed because it was just outputting "D" infinitely.

```
  var langs = data;

  function walk(obj) {
    for (var key in obj) {
      if (obj.hasOwnProperty(key)) {
        var val = obj[key];
        console.log(val);
        walk(val);
      }
    }
  }
  walk(langs);
```

Latest thing that worked was this:

```
var langs = data;
console.log(data.languages); // >[Object object] ("english:{}, russian:{}" I suppose)
console.log(data.languages.english); // >[Object object] ("dontRefresh":"...",} I suppose)
// BUT
console.log(data.languages.english['dontRefresh']); // > Undefined
```

What I'm trying to achieve is get the value of dontRefresh key. Simple enough, doesn't work.

Comment: There is no `data.languages.english`. I'm not sure how `console.log(data.languages.english)` returns `// >[Object object]`. You probably want  `data.languages[0].english` since `languages` is an array with one object

Comment: Languages is an _array of objects_ (also called a _collection_).  You need to find the one who's key matches what you are looking for (say, English), and then access it that way.  Put another way, the path to English's dontRefresh is actually `data.languages[0].english.dontRefresh`

Comment: @cale_b Thank you! This one works like a charm. Though I don't understand why is there a [0] after languages. Is it because of []'s?

Comment: Yes.  `[]` means an array, which is a sequential numeric index.  So `data = ['foo', 'bar']` is an array, and to access the value `bar`, you'd use `data[1]`.  Your structure is more complex than this, but the concept is the same.

Answer (score 0):

At its core, your problem is simply that you're assuming strings aren't iterable.
Take this for example,

```
let string = 'abc';
for (key in string)
  console.log(key);
// 0
// 1
// 2
// formatUnicorn
// truncate
// splitOnLast
// contains
```

Realize your problem yet? No?

Well, let's take the first iteration, where `key` is `'0'`. Does `string.hasOwnProperty('0')` return true? Yes.

This means we're going to recursively call walk on `string[0]`. What is `string[0]`? 'a', Another STRING!

Essentially, you'll infinitely iterate over the first character of the string when you pass a string to your walk algorithm. Luckily, it's easy to check for strings in JS using the `typeof` operator ([mdn](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/typeof)): `typeof 'string' === 'string'`:

```js
var data = {
"languages" : [{

  "english" :  {
    "dontRefresh" : "Do not refresh the page!",
    "funFact" : "kittens are nutritious!!!",
  }, 
  "russian" : {
  },
}] 
}

function walk(obj) {
    if (typeof obj === 'string')
      console.log(obj);
    else
      for (var key in obj) {
        if (obj.hasOwnProperty(key)) {
          var val = obj[key];
          walk(val);
        }
      }
}

walk(data);
```